# Get record that was just inserted in web.py

Tags: web.py

When I insert a record into a database in web.py, I noticed that the insert doesn't return back the record I just inserted. How can I get this record, or at least a specific column in this record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`db.insert` returns the last insert id, to get the record you should select it using `db.select`.

Comment: But what is this "insert id". How do I query/select on it? Is it some field in my table I'm unaware of?

Comment: The value of the primary key of the new record in your table.

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU! This is what I wanted to know. Thank you so much! To the Web.py developers out there, I love Web.py but this point should be made clearer in the Web.py documentation.